# Select a column two times to seperate data that I'm viewing (DATES)

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm trying to get a date column to display two times in order to have one column for a specific type and the other column for a different type that way when I deal with SSRS I can manipulate the data easier.

For example:

```
ID   |   Type   |   DocDate   |
-------------------------------
1    |   Lic    |   12/1/12   |
1    |   Med    |   6/3/12    |
```

What I want is this

```
ID   |   Type   |   LicDate   |   MedDate  |
--------------------------------------------
1    |   Lic    |   12/1/12   |   NULL     |
1    |   Med    |   NULL      |   6/3/12   |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CASE statement to display data conditionally:

```
SELECT ID, Type, 
       CASE WHEN Type='Lic' THEN DocDate ELSE NULL END AS LicDate,
       CASE WHEN Type='Med' THEN DocDate ELSE NULL END AS MedDate
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Actually, you don't even need `ELSE NULL` though I have no problem with being explicit like that.

Comment: I kinda like seeing complete logic, so there're no unexplained results

Comment: That did work even though I had this already... I must have just been dumb and not noticed that there was only 1 field filled in for MedDate out of the thousands that I have.   EDIT-Thank you.